# how to remove index of array inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove an index in an array inside a bigger arrays;
for example:

```
 let myArray = [
  [{general : true, name: 'a' },{general : true, name: 'b' },{general : false, name: 'c' }],
  [{general : false, name: 'd' },{general : true, name: 'e' },{general : false, name: 'f'}],
  [{general : true, name: 'i' },{general : false, name: 'h' },{general : false, name: 'g' }]
]
```

I want to remove all objects with `general == false` to get this:

```
myFilteredArray = [
      [{general : true, name: 'a' },{general : true, name: 'b' }],
      [{general : true, name: 'e' }],
      [{general : true, name: 'i' }]
    ]
```

I did this but it doesn't work:

```
let l = myArray.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
          if(!myArray[i][j].general){
            myArray[i].splice(j,1)
          }
        }
      }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you have two objects with `general: false` next to each other. You're looking at index `j`, and possibly removing that entry, and then moving on to the next entry after it — but when you remove an entry, the one after it moves up to index `j` and never gets checked.

Three options:

1. When you remove the entry, decrement `j` so you check the entry that moved on the next pass.
2. Loop backward from the end.
3. Use `filter` to create *new* arrays, rather than modifying arrays in place, perhaps combined with `map` on the outer array:

#2 is more popular than #1:

```
let l = myArray.length;
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (let j = myArray[i].length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (!myArray[i][j].general) {
            myArray[i].splice(j,1)
        }
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
let myArray = [
    [{general : true, name: 'a' },{general : true, name: 'b' },{general : false, name: 'c' }],
    [{general : false, name: 'd' },{general : true, name: 'e' },{general : false, name: 'f'}],
    [{general : true, name: 'i' },{general : false, name: 'h' },{general : false, name: 'g' }]
];

let l = myArray.length;
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (let j = myArray[i].length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (!myArray[i][j].general) {
            myArray[i].splice(j,1)
        }
    }
}
console.log(myArray);
```

Here's #3:

```
myArray = myArray.map(subarray => subarray.filter(({general}) => general));
```

Live example:

```js
let myArray = [
    [{general : true, name: 'a' },{general : true, name: 'b' },{general : false, name: 'c' }],
    [{general : false, name: 'd' },{general : true, name: 'e' },{general : false, name: 'f'}],
    [{general : true, name: 'i' },{general : false, name: 'h' },{general : false, name: 'g' }]
];

myArray = myArray.map(subarray => subarray.filter(({general}) => general));
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Your 3rd is the best

Comment: @mplungjan - That's very situationally-dependent. It's the one I'd use if I didn't have a good reason not to, though.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out reduce is a solid solution

```js
let myArray = [
  [{general : true, name: 'a' },{general : true, name: 'b' },{general : false, name: 'c' }],
  [{general : false, name: 'd' },{general : true, name: 'e' },{general : false, name: 'f'}],
  [{general : false, name: 'x' },{general : false, name: 'y' },{general : false, name: 'z' }], // all false
  [{general : true, name: 'i' },{general : false, name: 'h' },{general : false, name: 'g' }]
]

const filtered = myArray.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  let flt = arr.filter(item => item.general)
  if (flt.length) acc.push(flt) 
  return acc; 
},[]);

console.log(filtered)
```

I first thought this, but it is not matching OP's output.

```js
let myArray = [
  [{general : true, name: 'a' },{general : true, name: 'b' },{general : false, name: 'c' }],
  [{general : false, name: 'd' },{general : true, name: 'e' },{general : false, name: 'f'}],
  [{general : true, name: 'i' },{general : false, name: 'h' },{general : false, name: 'g' }]
]

const filtered = myArray.map(arr => arr.filter(item => item.general)).flat()

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: @kopischke Not sure I understand

Comment: But if I do that, then it does not look like OP wants - then it looks like my second example

Comment: Ah, sorry, totally misread that, my bad. Forget my remarks.

Comment: The second code example has thrown me. Your first one works as intended, correct? Upvoted.

Comment: `reduce` when you're not doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducers is overcomplicated at the best of times, but particularly so when the value being carried around (the new array) never changes. Just use a loop. (Or, of course, the `map`/`filter` we both like. :-) )

Comment: Hm, sort of get that - I like the name reduce because that is what OP wants to do. Reduce to only arrays with true